# Last two unique entries in sorted pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is sorted by two columns (id and Name):

```
ix   id      Value   Name

39   837     Value1  Name1
40   838     Value2  Name1
16   811     Value3  Name2
26   821     Value4  Name2
27   822     Value5  Name2
10   805     Value6  Name3
11   806     Value7  Name3
```

Id like to return a data frame with the last two unique Values for each name e.g.

```
ix   id      Value   Name

39   837     Value1  Name1
40   838     Value2  Name1
26   821     Value4  Name2
27   822     Value5  Name2
10   805     Value6  Name3
11   806     Value7  Name3
```

There could be several 'Values' per name, not just the one given in this example.
Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
df.groupby('Name')\                      
  .apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates()\  # find unique elements
                    .tail(2))\           # last two
  .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)       # remove groupby index
```

Comment: That got it. Ace. Thank you for your help and swift reply!

Comment: @user3182080, glad to hear! Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.